# Modify VBA to split text string in pasted cells

Tags: vba, excel

I have the below code and need to add a function to the y.sheets that will allow for me to split a couple of text strings in column A after the rangecells have been pasted to "Jan".

Basically I would like to split the string "PB Volume" when it appears in Column A on the y.sheets.

```
  Private Sub CommandButton22_Click()
Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook


'## Open both workbooks first:
Set x = Workbooks.Open("Worksheet to Copy")
Set y = Workbooks.Open("Worksheet to Paste")


Dim Rangecells As Variant
    For Each Rangecells In Split("A1:ax10000", ",")
        'Now, copy what you want from x:
        x.Sheets("Report Data").Range(Rangecells).Copy


        'Now, paste to y worksheet:

        y.Sheets("Jan").Range(Rangecells).PasteSpecial
        y.Sheets("Jan").Cells.UnMerge




    Next

'Close x:
x.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Too little detail here to make any real suggestions.  Sasmple data and expected results would help.

Comment: @TimWilliams was that more helpful? I just need to split any cell in column A that is Pasted in "Jan" that contains the string "PB Volume"

Comment: What does "split" mean?  Turn one text string into two?  Paste two segments of a string into separate cells?  Unmerge cells so two cells appear?

Comment: @Smandoli split would mean using space as the delimiter and splitting the cell into two

Comment: where should those two parts go?

Comment: @TimWilliams keep PB in column A and put Volume in column B

Answer (score 0):

Untested:

```
Dim c as Range, arr

With y.Sheets("Jan")
    .Range(Rangecells).PasteSpecial
    .Cells.UnMerge
    For each c in Application.Intersect(.UsedRange,.Columns(1)).Cells
        If c.value = "PB Volume" Then
             arr = split(c.value, " ")
             c.value = arr(0)
             c.offset(0,1).value=arr(1)
        End If
    Next c
End With
```